# Ajax hyperlinking

Tags: php, ajax, hyperlink

I have a problem in giving Ajax functionality to a hyperlink. I have files `Link.html` and `GetCustomerdata.php`. The main function of the HTML is send the data to `getCutomerData.php` and shows flash as "success".

And also I do not want hyperlinking,

```
<a href="#"
```

Instead I need it in terms of:

```
<a href=GetCustomer.php?id=<format>
```

Is it possible to clear?

#### Link.Html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Customer Account Information</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var url = "GetCustomerData.php?id="; // The server-side script
            function handleHttpResponse() {
                if (http.readyState == 4) {
                    if(http.status==200) {
                        var results=http.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('divCustomerInfo').innerHTML = results;
                    }
                }
            }

            function requestCustomerInfo() {
                var sId =10;
                document.getElementById("txtCustomerId").value;
                http.open("GET", url + escape(sId), true);
                http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
                http.send(null);
            }

            function getHTTPObject() {
                var xmlhttp;

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                    if (window.ActiveXObject){
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        if (!xmlhttp){
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                    }
                return xmlhttp;
            }

            var http = getHTTPObject();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="getCustomerData.php?id=10&onclick="requestCustomerInfo();return false;">Show Me</a>
        <div id="divCustomerInfo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...

And my PHP file just flashes the suceess message:

#### getCustomerData.php

```
<?php
    echo "Success"
?>
```

Comment: you already start the same question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377854](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the anchor onclick event inside the href attribute. onclick should be written as a separate attribute:

```
...
<a href="getCustomerData.php?id=10" onclick="requestCustomerInfo();return false;">Show Me</a>
```

To prevent the link from redirecting the page, you need to stop the click event from executing the link default action. Inside your function call:

```
function requestCustomerInfo(event) {
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```